# In cocoa, how can I close (quit) the main window but keep the status item running?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In my cocoa app, I have a main window to display main content. 
Also there's a status item in system status bar (top right) to receive event after the main window is closed.

When I press cmd+q in my app, the main window and status item all quit. 
How can I make the status item part keep running?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a different application that shows the status item.

One application would run constantly and show the item.

The other is the principal application, running when you need it.

Comment: Can these 2 applications be packaged into one .app and installed together? Any documentation?

Comment: After some searching, maybe NSWorkspace can help.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 options.

1. You seperate the normal application with the window and the statusbar.
2. You only hide the window. You can create a new action (for example called -(IBAction)hideWindow;) and connect it with the "terminate NSMenuItem" in the MainMenu (with Interface builder)